# Basic Probability Law Proof

Tags: probability

I'm trying to show that

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Here's my attempt:

Proof: There are two cases.  Either $$A \cap B = \emptyset$$ or not.

Suppose the former.  Then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$  But since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $$P(A) + P(B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$ since $$P(A \cap B) = 0$$

Suppose $$A \cap B \neq \emptyset$$.  Then $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B \cap A^c)$$  But I'm not totally sure where to go from here...

Ideas?

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that 
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A \cap B') + P(A' \cap B) + P(A \cap B)
$$ using the fact that 
$$(A\cup B) = (A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$$
and each of those events is independent.

Then simply rewrite $P(A\cap B')$ as $P(A) - P(A \cap B)$ (*by the definition of $P(A \cap B')$*) , and proceed similarly for $P(A' \cap B)$, then after some substitution you should be there.

Comment: Aren't you missing a term when you rewrite $$P(A \cap B^c)$$?  Also, in the first case in my proof above, I'm not convinced it's right b/c I jump from $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$ to $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) + P(A \cap B)$$ since the last term is 0.  But by the same argument, I could have said $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) + 5 * P(A \cap B)$$ which is obviously wrong...how would you amend?

Comment: @bclayman I don't believe so. What term do you think I am missing?

Comment: Well, you say $$P(A \cup B) = P(A \cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap B)$$, so then I'd think $$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A \cup B) - P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap B)$$, no?

Comment: @bclayman At that step, I am not simply rearranging my first formula. I am using the definition of $P(A \cap B')$. _By definition_, $P(A \cap B')$ is equal to $P(A) - P(A \cap B)$. Can you understand why?

Comment: I see now.  Would you mind commenting on my above comment?  The one about $$5 * P(A \cap B)$$?

Comment: @bclayman Ah, I didn't notice your edit. Yes, that's an incorrect jump in logic, to simply add that term because they are not disjoint, unless you manage to justify it, which you didn't. An even bigger jump in logic is to multiply that term by $5$. When attempting to prove even really simple things, especially in probability theory, I find you usually end up constructing results rather directly from definitions, as I did in this case.